# Using '::after' selector with immediate sibling '+' selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this basic HTML structure:

```
<div class="cotnainer">
    <div class="left">  1 </div>
    <div class="right"> 2 </div>
    <div class="right"> 3 </div>
    <div class="left">  4 </div>
    <div class="right"> 5 </div>
    <!-- continuing on in a variable order -->
</div>
```

I need to apply an `::after` style to the last element of each type before the class changes sides.

*i.e. I need to apply the style to 1, 3 and 4 in the above example*

These elements will be generated dynamically

I have tried CSS selectors like:

```
.right + .right::after, .left + .left::after { ... }
//this misses the individual elements

.right::after, .left::after { ...apply style... }
.right::after + .right, .left::after + .left { ...remove ::after style from preceeding elements... }
//this was an attempt to remove the generally applied style from preceeding elements
```

Any help, ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit:** As this question has remained an issue for me I started a bounty to further solicit solutions and ideas to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Note: You using `.left + left::after`, use like this: `.left + .left::after` (missed dot)

Comment: Couldn't you go with something like `.left + .right::before {}`?

Comment: Instead of applying `::after` to the last element of each type, could you apply `::before` to the first one after the change?

Comment: The `::before` method doesn't work because i need the style to be relative to the previous element. Thanks though.

Comment: unfortunatly, you can't use CSS to select the previous element in the markup. Have you considered using the before pseudo element on the tag after the class change? Otherwise as your content is dynamic, you will need JS to select your element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS cannot do this. The proper solution is to group your rows; use common-sense semantic HTML if possible.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left {
  background: #6AF;
}
.right {
  background: #6CF;
}
.left > li:last-child::after {
  content: " (last child of .left)";
}
.right > li:last-child::after {
  content: " (last child of .right)";
}
```

```html
<div class="cotnainer">
  <ul class="left">
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="left">
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

<sup>I used ul/li in the above example but see if there is a better element that matches the semantics.</sup>

Comment: If the OP can group the elements, he can just as easily tag the "last of group" element with additional class.

Comment: The idea is to achieve the desired result with HTML, not CSS.

Comment: Your solution changes HTML structure and provides CSS to go with it. Without the provided CSS, the "HTML solution" doesn't really do anything. Adding additional class to the "last in group" element is also change in HTML structure + CSS to suit it. But both the HTML adjustments and required CSS are smaller in the latter case.

Comment: There is no pure CSS solution unless the markup is changed or some helper class is added. I am asking not to fight CSS selectors; if the data is some kind of group (this is my assumption) then group it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CSS does not provide a way to select "last of class". Consider applying a specific class to target with ::after, or you can use some JavaScript to do your selecting.

Comment: I was afraid that I was going to have to use javascript to handle the selections. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara The last-of-type pseudo selector can only select elements (tags), not classes.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As far as I know, I don't think you can do this with CSS alone.</strike>
Looks like Boris is right.

```
.left + .right,
.right + .left {
    color:red;
}
```

Would probably do it.
You learn something new every day!

---

You could do it with jQuery, however, with something like:

JQuery

```
var lastElemHasClassLeft = false;
    $('.cotnainer > div').each(function(key, val) {
    if (lastElemHasClassLeft != $(this).hasClass('left')) {
        $(this).addClass('change');
    }
    lastElemHasClassLeft = $(this).hasClass('left');
});
```

CSS

```
.change::after {
    content: 'hello';
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hxxhumq/